# Reference not responding to emails, should I find another reference instead?

Tags: references

I applied for a job that is asking for 3 references. I have two secured already, but the third, despite them having wrote me a recommendation before, is not responding to their emails, despite them having been prompt with me when they wrote their original recommendation.

Its been over a week, and I have tried to followup with them a couple of times already. I already gave the HR person the other two references in the meantime, but I am still stuck waiting on this last reference.

Is it worth sticking with this reference, or should I be better off trying to find a new one to fill the hole here?

EDIT: I finally got in touch with them. Probably that they were busy, but also likely it was a spam issue.

Comment: Only you can answer how valuable that particular reference is in comparison to another reference.

Comment: There used to be a time when August was vacation time. There used to be a time where people were not reachable during vacation time. Some people remember the good old times. Your actions depend on your urgency.

Comment: Some people tend to not use the telephone so much as others, so not always an effective solution.

Comment: @joe, Normally I would be able to go to office hours. However, aside from the fact I'm physically away, we're in the middle of a pandemic which limits options of being able to get in contact with them.

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes, obviously". The answer to the question you should have asked is "_before_ providing their information as reference".

Answer (score 3):

I would give them a call instead of email as Joe S mentioned, but one should have more references in reserve.  So instead of depending on the same three, perhaps as many as six lined up, especially if your references might be on a demanding project or have family or health issues (even more so with the COVID-19 impact).  If you provide references in excess of the number requested, you might also tell the extra people that they are off the hook as the hiring manager has received the requisite number of references or otherwise indicated that they are satisfied with what they have already received (a more diplomatic approach).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend finding another reference or calling as Mike mentioned. They may be busy and may have forgotten, so calling can help instead of sending emails.